# How to make a custom loss in Keras with the log-likelihood of a multivariate gaussian?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, loss-function, log-likelihood

I am trying to replicate the first experiment about function regression in the paper [conditional neural processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01613), using Keras.

I am therefore using the negative log-likelihood of my observations as a loss function. My network outputs two values, the mean and the standard deviation of each observation. Since the network can take a variable number of target points as input, my batches have shape [None,None,2] (for [batch_size, number_of_target_points, output_size]) at the output of the decoder. The way I am currently defining my custom loss is in the following way:

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    mu, sigma = tf.split(y_pred, 2, axis=-1)
    dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=sigma)
    loss = - tf.reduce_mean(K.log(dist.log_prob(y_true)))
    return loss

opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
model.compile(loss = custom_loss,optimizer = opt)
```

However, I am getting a loss `nan` during training at every epochs, like this

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 7s 57ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong and how I could fix it ?

Note that it is ensured that the standard deviation is positive and not too small with a variance flooring layer at the end of the network:

```
def floor_variance(x):
  # Repeat r vector
  mu, log_sigma = tf.split(x, 2, axis=-1)
  sigma = 0.1 + 0.9 * tf.nn.softplus(log_sigma)
  return K.concatenate([mu, sigma], axis=-1)

[... define the network ... ]
x = Lambda(floor_variance, name = 'Floor_variance')(x) # x shape [None,None,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like line 4 is taking a log twice. You probably don't want the K.log() there.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an old problem, but I would suggest you to sum up a small quantity (e.g., 1e-6) to the argument of the log() to avoid log(0), which would give -inf.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).